# Load html content on a local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed some touchscreen content that will be run on a local machine at an event. It will be run full screen using Chrome, and I need to load various html content dynamically into a container. Is this possible, as the usual JQuery load() and ajax methods only seem to work when running off of a server. All the content sits in its own folder as a html file, so I just need to point to the correct html file as and when needed.

Is there a way to do this when all content is being run locally?

Comment: Seems like running a local web server would be a reasonable approach.  Does the OS you're using not come with one?

Comment: you have to serve the content via a server. Browsers do not have access to the file system besides the upload form.

Comment: If needed I can always run it through XAMP or WAMP. It's just that it's extra hassle for the stand builders to set this up first, as I won't be on site to do it myself. Was wondering if there's a way to do it where they just have to launch the index file and they are good to go.

Comment: FireFox can do AJAX requests also with file protocol, for reading only, though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not running an http server. You can't get ajax from the file:// protocol. You need to run a local http server.

- If your backend language is javascript, you should run nodejs
- If your backend is php you should probably run apache2

Comment: Offer OP some suggestions and I'll upvote your answer. Otherwise this could've just been a comment.

Comment: as an aside, just use an iframe and change the src.

Comment: added suggestions @JonUleis